# JavaScript - React-Quill | Styled tags are gone after first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

I'm using QuillJS in my react app and after every reload, the first time I open the component all styling (span with inline styles) is gone. If I close and reopen it without reloading the page the styling is back.

Can anyone help me out?